# How to determine if and when a point and triangle moving uniformly will collide?

Tags: line-of-sight, fog-of-war

**TLDR;** I just learned this problem can be simplified to:  **How to determine the time at which a uniformly moving point will intersect with a stationary triangle?**  Also, how to figure out the time when the point will exit the triangle?

I have a player with a triangular line of sight ("field of vision" would be more a accurate term here).  I also have an NPC, represented by a point.  Currently I have the server update the client about both their positions only when one of them changes speed or direction of movement.

Without a limited field of vision, I was able to solve this.  How I intend to solve this new problem is as follows:

- Each time either the player or NPC changes speed or direction (speed is a boolean at the moment, 1 or 0, and will probably remain that way), figure out if a line drawn from the point NPC to the edge of the game "room" at the angle of it's current direction, is within a triangle consisting of one point at the player's current position, and the other two points at the location they would be if the player were to reach the edge of the room moving at their current angle.
- If the above is false, we can ignore the following steps because it means the NPC can't enter the vision field.  But if true, continue.
- Figure out at what time the NPC will intersect the player's field of vision.  This, I do not know how to do, but I expect there is some formula I can use instead of checking every tick.
- But once I do have this formula, I will use it's return value to set a timer that, when it goes off, will have the server update the client and tell it the location of the NPC.
- Then I will have to also figure out at what time the NPC will **exit** the field of vision, and tell the client to delete or inactivate that NPC.

Does anyone know what mathematical formula I'm looking for?  I need to figure out when a moving point will intersect a moving triangle, when they are both moving uniformly (not changing direction or speed).  Also, the point in time when the point will exit the triangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you shoot the ball through a triangle, it will hit exactly 2 sides before it exits from it. So you can just get the 2 sides it will collide with, the one it does it first with will be the one it enters through, the other one is the one it exits through.

Let's say the ball is at position \$(x_0; y_0)\$, moves at a speed of \$(vx; vy)\$ and the 2 points of one side of the triangle are \$(x_1; y_1)\$ and \$(x_2;y_2)\$. These are the constants. The time the ball hits the side at this speed will be \$t\$. This is the unknown.

We can write the equation ot the side like so:

$$y(x)=x(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$$

The position of the ball at time \$t\$ is

$$x_b=x_0+t\cdot vx$$
$$y_b=y_0+t\cdot vy$$

The ball hits the side when these two values satisfy the equation presented earlier. If we substitute these values, we get

$$y_b=x_b(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$$
$$y_0+t\cdot vy=(x_0+t\cdot vx)(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$$

We need to find \$t\$ so we need to rearrange the equation

$$y_0+t\cdot vy=x_0(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)+t\cdot vx(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)$$

$$t\cdot vy-t\cdot vx(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)=x_0(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)-y_0$$
$$t(vy-vx(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1))=x_0(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)-y_0$$
$$t=\frac{x_0(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)-y_0}{vy-vx(y_2-y_1)/(x_2-x_1)}$$

Since everything on the right side is known, you can calculate t. Do this for every side. The 4 possible outcomes:

- One t is negative, the other two are positive: the smallest of the two positive ones is the entry point, the largest is the exit
- Only one t is positive: This means that the start point is inside the triangle, the only positive side is the exit.
- Neither are positive: The ball won't hit the triangle.
- One calculation isn't possible, because the denominator is 0: this means the the side and the direction of the ball are paralell. Just treat it as a very large negative number.